# Design pattern for complete new changes

Tags: java, design-patterns

I need to create new file with new specifications each time for a new integration. Which design pattern is best suitable for this? Each time a new method is needed so as to implement a new file as it's different.

Currently I am adding new method in a single class.

```
public class FileGenerator {
    public void createJSONFile() {
      ///
    }

    public void createXMLFile() {
    }

    public void createCSVFile() {
    }

// ....this keeps on adding 
}
```

Is Strategy pattern the right option for this type of requirement?

Comment: Yes, strategy pattern looks suitable in this case.

Comment: Assuming you mean that each `create` method becomes a new subclass of `FileGenerator`, then yes, it's a great solution.